# How to find most recently updated value for each column

Tags: crystal-reports

Welcome to my first post ever.  I have a report where I am extracting the values from an audit log, and would like to display the most recent value for each result, giving me a snapshot of the current information.  For example for the data below I would like to have

```
                 **APP   Application Function   5    2020   EIS**
```

Basically the top non - value from each column in the attached image.

[My data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFDeE.jpg)

Each of the values except for the date is derived from a formula that parses an audit log.  I am grouping them by audit date, and using - for non edited fields, and I am using Crystal Reports 2013.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you want the max() of each column grouped by your date field?

Comment: Not the max of each column, but the most recent non zero value of each column.

Comment: you'll need to determine your max(timestamp) value for each field where the field value is not null, and then look up the related field value corresponding to its max(timestamp).  If you have a pivot function in your upstream data source, you can use that.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try.